# DotNetty: IllegalReferenceCountException

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm trying to implement DotNetty but have a strange issue?

Error message:

> DotNetty.Buffers.IllegalReferenceCountException: 'Illegal reference count of 0 for this object'

Image of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOI4w.png

Where does it happen?

```
public bool HasLength => Buffer.GetInt(0) > -1;
```

Here is the full class.

```
public class ServerPacket
{
    public IByteBuffer Buffer { get; }
    public short Id { get; private set; }

    public ServerPacket(short id)
    {
        Buffer = Unpooled.Buffer();
        Id = id;
        Buffer.WriteInt(-1);
        Buffer.WriteShort(id);
    }

    public bool HasLength =>
        Buffer.GetInt(0) > -1;

    public void WriteByte(int b) =>
        Buffer.WriteByte((byte)b);

    public void WriteDouble(double d) =>
        WriteString(d.ToString());

    public void WriteString(string s) // d
    {
        Buffer.WriteShort(s.Length);
        Buffer.WriteBytes(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s));
    }

    public void WriteShort(int s) =>
        Buffer.WriteShort(s);

    public void WriteInteger(int i) =>
        Buffer.WriteInt(i);

    public void WriteBoolean(bool b) =>
        Buffer.WriteByte(b ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Here is the class that calls `HasLength` method.

```
public class Encoder : MessageToMessageEncoder<ServerPacket>
{
    protected override void Encode(IChannelHandlerContext context, ServerPacket message, List<Object> output)
    {
        if (!message.HasLength)
        {
            message.Buffer.SetInt(0, message.Buffer.WriterIndex - 4);
        }

        output.Add(message.Buffer);
    }
}
```

How do I send an instance of ServerPacket?

```
public void SendPacket(ServerPacket packet)
{
    _context.WriteAndFlushAsync(packet);
}
```

This error happens when sending an instance of ServerPacket, here is the code.

```
class ObjectAddComposer : ServerPacket
{
    public ObjectAddComposer(Item Item)
        : base(ServerPacketHeaders.ObjectAddMessageComposer)
    {
        WriteInteger(Item.Id);
        WriteInteger(Item.GetBaseItem().SpriteId);
        WriteInteger(Item.GetX);
        WriteInteger(Item.GetY);
        WriteInteger(Item.Rotation);
        WriteString(String.Format("{0:0.00}", TextHandling.GetString(Item.GetZ)));
        WriteString(String.Empty);

        if (Item.LimitedNo > 0)
        {
            WriteInteger(1);
            WriteInteger(256);
            WriteString(Item.ExtraData);
            WriteInteger(Item.LimitedNo);
            WriteInteger(Item.LimitedTot);
        }
        else
        {
            ItemBehaviourUtility.GenerateExtradata(Item, this);
        }

        WriteInteger(-1); // to-do: check
        WriteInteger((Item.GetBaseItem().Modes > 1) ? 1 : 0);
        WriteInteger(Item.UserID);
        WriteString(Item.Username);
    }
}
```